# Mongodb whole index scanned, very slow, using WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, indexing, wiredtiger

I have a Device collection with the following index set up:

```
{
  "v" : 1,
  "key" :
  { "sdk.id" : 1, 
    "sdk.createdAt" : 1, 
    "sdk.updatedAt" : 1, 
    "deviceInfo.isTablet" : 1 },
  "name" : "sdk.id_1_sdk.createdAt_1_sdk.updatedAt_1_deviceInfo.isTablet_1",
  "ns" : "company.Device"
}
```

My document is like:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("something"),
   property: 'abcd',
   sdk: [
      { id: 'ab', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      { id: 'ac', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
   ]
}
```

When I do `db.Device.explain(1).find({'sdk.id': 'ab'}).count()` I get:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "company.Device",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "sdk.id" : {
                "$eq" : "ab"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "sdk.id" : 1,
                    "sdk.createdAt" : 1,
                    "sdk.updatedAt" : 1,
                    "deviceInfo.isTablet" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "sdk.id_1_sdk.createdAt_1_sdk.updatedAt_1_deviceInfo.isTablet_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 712,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 569865,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 636,
            "works" : 569865,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 569864,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 4452,
            "restoreState" : 4452,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 569863,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
                "nReturned" : 569863,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 616,
                "works" : 569864,
                "advanced" : 569863,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 4452,
                "restoreState" : 4452,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 569865,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "sdk.id" : 1,
                    "sdk.createdAt" : 1,
                    "sdk.updatedAt" : 1,
                    "deviceInfo.isTablet" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "sdk.id_1_sdk.createdAt_1_sdk.updatedAt_1_deviceInfo.isTablet_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "rs-primary",
        "port" : 27000,
        "version" : "3.0.2",
        "gitVersion" : "6201872043ecbbc0a4cc169b5482dcf385fc464f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

As you can see the request is very very slow and it appens only since we switched to WiredTiger (was immediate before).

The collection contains ~600k documents and there is ~550k documents with `sdk.id` $eq ab.

Can someone explain me the explain above? I can't find any information about isEOF, saveState and restoreState

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**isEOF**: Specifies whether the execution stage has reached end of stream

**saveState and restoreState** : In Mongo 3.0 these are counters for the number of times a query stage yielded (saveState) and then resumed (restoreState). For example, a collection scan (COLLSCAN) stage might need to yield to fetch documents that aren’t in memory yet. Queries also yield so they can be interleaved with other queries and safely stopped via $maxTimeMS or kill operations.

These are not very interesting numbers on their own. If you run multiple successive explains of the same query you’ll notice the numbers change based on other operations at the time as well as whether all the required documents were in memory at the time.